# Вычисления javascript

Tags: вывод, javascript

Написал программу на javascript которая вычисляет работу электрического тока по спрот..... ну не в этом суть. Когда я нажимаю расчитать он мне выдаёт вот такой результат: 240.00000000000006. Откуда эта шертёрка вообще взялась? И как её убрать? Вот скрин https://pp.vk.me/c413218/v413218182/6618/oPubYm-IIx0.jpg . А и ещё вопрос. Можно ли как нибуть убрать поле с ответом чтобы были одни цифри или что бы просто нельзя было в него ничего вводить?

Comment: Оффтопик. Вспомнилась картинка: http://habrastorage.org/storage2/8d4/321/4d0/8d43214d0a7782e569b617582ca02025.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция toFixed для числа, такие неточности бывают.
В поле можно поставить атрибут disabled="disabled".

Comment: Про disabled я знаю но оно затемняет.

Comment: @Perkovec, [readonly][1] + убрать border.

   [1]:http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/readonly

Comment: Хочу задать ещё один вопрос чтобы не создавать новую тему: на картинке видно что кнопка вдавлена и так со всеми на этой странице после нажатия. Сделано на jquery. @Deonis спасибо большое, полазил по этому скйту нашёл ещё много нужного.

Comment: Новичкам рекомендую прочитать статью под названием [Числа][1] на сайте javascript.ru. Если этого материала окажется мало, то читайте про [тип Number][2] в стандарте языка.


[1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/number#неточные-вычисления
[2]: http://es5.javascript.ru/x8.html#x8.5

Comment: @Perkovec, пожалуйста, не пытайтесь задать несколько разных вопросов в одной теме. Это вносит большую путаницу. Этот форум тем и хорош, что информация хорошо структурирована: один вопрос - одна страница. И ничего лишнего

Answer (score 1):

.00000000000006 возникает из-за того, что вещественные числа в компьютерах представляются с некоторой конечной точностью. Не подскажу хорошую ссылку на русском, но вкратце, типичная точность - порядка 15 десятичных знаков. Кроме того, числа хранятся в виде N/2^M, где N и M - целые и имеют некоторый диапазон. Поэтому, например, некоторые конечные десятичные дроби не могут быть представлены. Хотя конкретно 240 может быть представлено точно. Следовательно, ошибка появилась в ходе вычислений.